# Django Wysiwyg and image (Summernote or Froala)

Tags: django, django-forms, froala

I've been trying to integrate a WYSIWYG editor into my Django project. I first started with Summernote and I had no issue integrating the it into admin or a form. I followed the instructions on their github and everything works great except image uploading and inserting. I can press the upload button and the file is uploading (I can see it in the filesystem) but it does not show up in the editor or in the resulting html.

I thought it was just Summernote and so I switched to Froala but I'm getting the exact same behavior. Is there something I'm missing with image upload inside a wysiwyg?

in forms.py I have the equivalent of

```
from django import forms
from froala_editor.widgets import FroalaEditor

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
        content = forms.TextField(widget=FroalaEditor)
```

Comment: you should post some of your code;  do you have the views setup for accepting the uploaded image via Sumernote or Froala?

Comment: @warath-coder I'm using the code from https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor/blob/master/README.rst I'll put the exact code up in the question. Thanks

Comment: @warath-coder is there documentation for how the view needs to be adjusted the accept the uploaded image? As far as I can see on the linked page all it calls for is url(r'^froala_editor/', include('froala_editor.urls')), in urls.py